# Align x axis in frequency plot of a list of dates

Tags: r, plot, alignment

I'm working with a set of data, each containing a list of 3 dates related to when one of three sequential actions is taken:

```
action.1 <- sample(seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'), as.Date('2010-02-01'), by="day"), 200, replace=TRUE)
action.2 <- action.1 + sample(seq(0,10,by=1), 200, replace=TRUE)
action.3 <- action.2 + sample(seq(0,40,by=1), 200, replace=TRUE)
```

In order to visualize how the durations between actions depend on when `action.1` is taken -- for example, does higher frequency of `action.1` prolong the time for taking `action.2`?, I plot

```
rankn <- rank(action.1, ties.method = "first")

attach(mtcars)
layout(matrix(c(1,2), 2, 1, byrow = TRUE))

d1 = min(action.1, action.2, action.3)
d2 = max(action.1, action.2, action.3)

plot(table(action.1))

plot(action.1, rankn, col="red3", xlim=c(d1, d2))
points(action.2, rankn, col='green3')
points(action.3, rankn, col='blue3')
```

and obtain this figure:
[image]

However, I cannot figure out how to align the two figures so that the upper bound of the x axis in the frequency plot coincides with the rightmost red dot. I tried setting `plot(table(action.1)), xlim=c(d1,d2))`, but it just made the top figure disappear. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the **common part** between lists, which should be `max(min(list_1), min(list_2),...)` to `min(max(list_1), max(list_2),...)`.

So the problem is with your `d2`: `d2 = 2010-03-15`, instead you should assign it with:

```
d2 <- min(max(action.1), max(action.2), max(action.3))
```

Then, `d2 = 2010-02-01`, also with `d1` I think, assign it with `d1 <- max(min(action.1), min(action.2), min(action.3))`. If this is your expected result(ignore the Chinese format):
[image]

**EDIT:**
I prefer to use `par(mfrow = c(2,1))` to manage the plot layout. So:

```
  par(mfrow = c(2,1))

  d1 <- max(min(action.1), min(action.2), min(action.3))
  d2 <- min(max(action.1), max(action.2), max(action.3))

  plot(table(action.1))

  plot(action.1, rankn, col="red3", xlim=c(d1, d2))
  points(action.2, rankn, col='green3')
  points(action.3, rankn, col='blue3')
```

Comment: Thanks! However, is there a way to set up the figure so that the all the data until ``d2=2010-03-15`` is shown on the lower plot, while the table plot has blank space after date ``min(max(action.1), max(action.2), max(action.3)) = 2010-02-01``?

Comment: The data type you are using(which is `table` ) makes it a little complicated, and I think probably the dumb solution may be adding some extra data to your `table(action.1)`, `date` from `2010-02-01` to `2010-03-15`, and there frequencies are all `0`.